# Run multiple instance of a program in parallel

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a command, let say `php process.php`. I want to run 1000 instance of this command to test load caused on the server. How can I do this?

Things to note:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should terminate all instance at once
- It is going to run on a single core processor so no need of advance feature like multi-threading.
- Nice to show current number of running instance on top
- Commands should output in the same terminal
- Commands requires no input

Answer (score 8):

You could use a script. Save the following as `run-parallel.sh`, and make it executable (`chmod +x run-parallel.sh`):

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
trap "pkill -P $$; kill -INT $$" INT

while read n
do
    "$@" &
done < <(seq 1000)
wait
```

Explanation:

- `trap ... INT` sets a command to be run when the `SIGINT` signal is received (which is the signal generated when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>).
- `$$` is the PID of the current process (that is, of the script itself). `pkill -P $$` kills those processes whose parent process i the script.
- It is convention that a program which catches `SIGINT` kill itself using `SIGINT` once it has tidied up. Hence, the `kill -INT $$`.
- `seq 1000` generates numbers from 1 to 1000.
- The `while` loop runs the command provided as arguments to the script once for each number from `seq`, and sends them to the background.
- Then we `wait` until all of the background processes finish executing.

Run it thus:

```
./run-parallel.sh php process.php
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `xargs`. Just print the name of the process you want 100 times and pass it to `xargs`:

```
perl -e 'print "/path/to/process.php\n" x 100' | xargs -P 100 -I {} php {}
```

The Perl command simply prints `/path/to/process.php` followed by a newline 100 times. This is then passed to `xargs` which is told to launch up to 100 parallel commands (`-P 100`). The `-I {}` tells `xargs` to replace the string `{}` with its input. Therefore, `php {}` is expanded to `php /path/to/process.php`. Since everything is done by `xargs`, a single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will kill all of them, and all output is printed to the same terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Master program to start 1000 times `php process.php`. Using `fork` and `exec` may be convenient if you use C. When the Master starts a new `php` process, it also records its `pid`.

Show current number of running instance: the Master can monitor the status of the subprocesses.

Ctrl+C should terminate all instance at once: the Master captures Ctrl+C signal, and kills all the subprocesses (`kill(pid, SIGKILL);`) or notifies them to exit.