# How to to run multiple clones in parallel?

Tags: bash, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Since I am working on **KVM**, I have encountered an issue while trying to run multiple scripts in parallel that calculate the time that each VM takes to be cloned from an image that exists on the same machine. 
For one VM instance, I used to run this command:

```
virt-clone --original $VM1 --auto-clone
```

and the result as following:

```
WARNING  Setting the graphics device port to autoport, in order to avoid conflicting.
Allocating 'VM1-clone-01.img'                               | 8.0 GB  00:05     
Clone 'VMImage1-clone01' created successfully.
```

The time this VM takes to be created is 5 seconds. I have put in a loop to iterate and create an image of the same VM multiple times, but the requirement now is to calculate the time 20 VMs to be created at the same time.

Is there any way I can do this using the script-shell?

Comment: you want to know how long time does script takes to create 20VMs? like the command 'time bash yourScript.sh'? maybe this can help you for parallel running part [Run multiple instance of a program in parallel](https://askubuntu.com/q/712776/283843)

Comment: I'd basically want to know the estimate time it would take to clone an image multiple times in parallel.